# how to retrieve same column data and display as group

Tags: php, mysql

a table named users_log contains users login and logout time and date, but i am not able to sort data as i intend.

> Query

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users_log WHERE u_id = 52 ORDER BY date_log')
```

> It sort data like

```
Fri 12 Jul 13 - 03:41:40 PM - 03:42:31 PM

Fri 12 Jul 13 - 05:35:40 PM - 05:42:31 PM

Sat 13 Jul 13 - 02:29:09 PM - 02:34:52 PM
```

> users_log table

```
log_id, u_id,  date_log,   logged_date,   login_time,   logout_time

2,      52,   2013-01-12, Fri 12 Jul 13,  03:41:40 PM,  03:42:31 PM
```

> as i intend to display data

```
         Fri 12 Jul 13
   03:41:40 PM - 03:42:31 PM
   05:35:40 PM - 05:42:31 PM
         Sat 13 Jul 13
   02:29:09 PM - 02:34:52 PM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users_log WHERE u_id = 52 ORDER BY date_log');
$sorting = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $sorting[$row['logged_date']][] = $row['login_time']."-".$row['logout_time'];
}

//Now you loop over the sorted data using foreach($sorting as $key => $value) and display it any way you want.
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Comment: thank you saran banarjee...it display as i want, but it show undefined offset 1

Comment: let me see the lines in the code foreach($sorting as $key => $value) you have done

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should do something like(i assume you want to do it in php):

```
SELECT date_log FROM users_log WHERE u_id = 52 GROUP BY date_log,
```

then iterate over results (in php) and get the corresponding rows for date:

```
SELECT * FROM users_log WHERE u_id = 52 AND date_log = $date_for_current_iteration ORDER BY date_log;
```